# Aptana crashes on ubuntu linux

Tags: java, linux, aptana3, linux-mint

Every time i open Aptana it crashes.

---

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

```
  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f14294b2c91, pid=5722, tid=139727004391168

 JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6ac91]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x11

 Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
```

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

Answer (score 2):

It happend to me after upgrade to ubuntu 14.04 using Oracle Java 7. In the Aptana folder there are hs_err_pid...log. Opening the last one of them I saw:

```
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
```

so, I did open a terminal and I worte directly:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

and it worked for me. No problems until now.

Comment: Worked for me as well on Ubuntu 14.04, Aptana 3.6 and Oracle Java 1.8.0_40. I don't see the relationship between the ability to write core dump, ulimits, and the location of the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a broken installation of Aptana, either caused by a bug in the Eclipse / Aptana codebase, or some incompatibility with your Ubuntu installation.

- If this was working before, try and find out what has changed recently.  (Did you install new plugins?  Did you apply some Ubuntu patches?  Did you update versions of your OS or Aptana?)
- If it never worked, check to see if your combination of Aptana and the OS are supported.

Either way, the most likely solution is going to be to reinstall, upgrade or downgrade something to get rid of the apparent incompatibility.

---

For the record, I suspect that this is related to the following Eclipse bug:

- [crash: fatal error in soup_session_feature_detach with WebKitGTK+ >= 1.11.91](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=404776)
- [libsoup2.4-1: Problem with Eclipse and java](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=705420)

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/fix-aptana-studio-3-crashing-in-ubuntu.html :

> In the folder where you've extracted / install Aptana Studio 3, you should have a file called "AptanaStudio3.ini" - open this file with a text editor and **at the end of the file**, add this line:
>
> `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla`

Comment: Please add some more informations with your answer as it may be looked at as a link-only answer. Giving that the link dies, the rest of your answer doesn't provide much informations.

Answer (score 0):

From what i gathered around the internet, it seems to be a problem with webkit, what did the trick for me was removing the library:

```
apt-get purge libwebkitgtk-1.0-common
```

The problem is, other programs like the gimp use that library...

Or you may turn off the contextual help like guyfromfl suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548097/aptana-crashes-after-upgrading-to-xubuntu-14-04/25005293#25005293)