# Aptana crashes after upgrading to Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: aptana

I have been using Aptana for years now, and have become accustom to its many features.

It has been reliable up until I upgraded from Xubuntu 13.04 to 14.04.

Now it crashes ever 5 or so minutes. I can't get work done. No error appears and the screen just disappears. I have to create my SFTP connections all over again each time i restart it.

I have looked in ~/Aptana Workspace/.metadata/.log but it does not have any information about why it is crashing.

If this means anything, 99% of my work is done on remote servers.

When Aptana sits with no files open it seems to stay open indefinitely.

I am using 3.4.2 standa alone on Xubuntu 14.04 64-bit with openjdk-7.
My system ram is currently at 31% (about 2.4GB) and htop's load average is 1.06 0.76 0.64 (I read most of the crashes are related to aptana loading up the memory, however it does not look like that here...)

If there is any logs I can post I will be happy to send them

**EDIT**
Here is my .log file after the latest crash:

```
!SESSION 2014-05-06 18:58:38.247 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_55
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2014-05-06 18:58:40.256
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing     workspace to recover changes.
!SESSION 2014-05-06 19:03:07.121 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_55
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2014-05-06 19:03:09.189
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing      workspace to recover changes.
!SESSION 2014-05-06 19:14:47.589 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_55
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2014-05-06 19:14:49.545
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing     workspace to recover changes.
```

I have tried purging anything associated with Aptana and Eclipse, as well as OpenJDK, and reinstalling but still doing the same.

I also checked

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Here is the output:

```
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/gij-4.8                                 1048      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1071      manual mode
```

**Another Edit** I removed OpenJDK and installed oracle java, no change

** EDIT 5/23/2014 CRASH FROM CLI **

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f9fc0c322a1, pid=7070, tid=140327171606272
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_05-b13) (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.5-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64  compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6c2a1]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x11
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/hs_err_pid7070.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Comment: I have the same issues on Ubuntu 14.04 after upgrading from 13.10. Does it usually crash when you do copy-paste actions or does it appear completely random? For me copy-pasting randomly crashes Aptana, and randomly coming back to the app e.g from alt-tabbing and as soon as I type something.

Comment: It seems to be pretty random, but I have noticed that it tends to happen when I paste also, but not consistently.

Comment: It does seem to happen often with scrolling with my mouse wheel.

Comment: I executed AptanaStudio from the command line .. inside /opt/Aptana_Studio_r/ I ran ./AptanaStudio3, I got the crash to happen and got an error message in the cli. I have appended it to my original post.

Comment: To anybody watching this thread, I have submitted a ticket with Appcelerator: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-8208?filter=-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open `AptanaStudio3.ini` and append this line to end of file:

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla
```

Comment: I put Windows->Preferences->Aptana Studio->Content Assist->Show Information on hover = "On" (Default setting) and this fix on 3 different Xubuntu computers and everything works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issues and exactly the same core dump error since upgraded to kubuntu 14.04.
So far i have changed/installed the following:

-Install aplication as http://www.samclarke.com/2012/04/how-to-install-aptana-studio-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin/

-Changed gtk2 theme to qtcurve (after installing qtcurve)

-Added instruction ulimit -c unlimited to AptanaStudio3.sh just before main program

Since these changes i have been working for more than half an hour without problems but can't be sure if the problem has been fixed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Added ulimit -c unlimited to the sh script...I will report back on how it goes for me. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still crashing

Answer (score 0):

I maybe jinxing myself by posting this so soon, but I have gotten Aptana to run stable for about 30 minutes.

What I did was disable the Show information on hover event.

Turn it off by going to Window->Preferences->Aptana Studio->Conent Assist and setting "Show information on hover" to Off.

If this doesn't fix it I will report back, but so far so good.

Credit:
[Aptana closes unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011391/aptana-closes-unexpectedly?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

From what i gathered around the internet, it seems to be a problem with webkit, what did the trick for me was removing the library:

```
apt-get purge libwebkitgtk-1.0-common
```

The problem is, other programs like the gimp use that library...

Or you may turn off the contextual help like guyfromfl suggested.