# Aptana Studio 3 Started Crashing

Tags: aptana, aptana3

(possible duplicate: [Aptana crashes after upgrading to Xubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548097/aptana-crashes-after-upgrading-to-xubuntu-14-04))

The Aptana Studio 3 IDE started crashing, it started doing this after doing a distribution update of Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04. Can't replicate the issue and it seems randomly, but usually it crashes when I do copy-paste actions or maybe actions that change the syntax highlighting (I'm not sure about the syntax highlighting).

The application simply closes without any error messages and creates a log file in my home directory.

Here are the contents of that log file: http://pastebin.com/Tm6mYBpp

**System Info**

- Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bit)
- Aptana Studio 3.4.2.201308081805

**Actions already taken:**

- Re-installation of Aptana Studio 3 (Didn't help)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issues and exactly the same core dump error since upgraded to kubuntu 14.04. So far i have changed/installed the following:

-Install aplication as http://www.samclarke.com/2012/04/how-to-install-aptana-studio-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin/

-Changed gtk2 theme to qtcurve (after installing qtcurve)

-Added instruction ulimit -c unlimited to AptanaStudio3.sh just before main program

Since these changes i have been working for more than half an hour without problems but can't be sure if the problem has been fixed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Any news if it's still acting up?