# Aptana 3 not working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, aptana3, workbench

Since upgrade from 13.10 Aptana is either not opening (Kubuntu) or with some kind of workbench error, or this, when trying to use browser preview (Ubuntu):

> Unhandled event loop exception
>
> No more handles [Could not detect registered XULRunner to use]

I'm working on a website with Aptana, all was ok before upgrade.

Comment: So how is one supposed to happily switch from Windows to Linux if software like this with issues like these do not get any feedback from anybody responsible for Aptana?

Comment: Maybe because this is not the Aptana support forum? https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=384463 looks like it's an issue with your installation.

Comment: The reference you point at is from 2012, so no relation to Ubuntu 14.04, also, as I mentioned, all was ok before Ubuntu upgrade, and yes, I understand this not an Aptana forum , then again, one is looking for "user level" support, not Dev level..., and yes, this is criticism to the whole Linux community and something debated in various forums regarding making it factible to switch from Win or Mac to Lin. , So, still waiting for a comprehensive reply, thnx.

Answer (score 0):

From what i gathered around the internet, it seems to be a problem with webkit, what did the trick for me was removing the library:

```
apt-get purge libwebkitgtk-1.0-common
```

The problem is, other programs like the gimp use that library...

Or you may turn off the contextual help like guyfromfl suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548097/aptana-crashes-after-upgrading-to-xubuntu-14-04/25005293#25005293)

Comment: Right, well, I DO use Gimp, so...thanks anyway. BTW; my crash is not on contextual help but on "browser preview".